# Flutter image adding and emulator running error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I want to add image in `android studio`. I created a folder named `"images"` inside the project and pasted the image I wanted to upload there. Then I did the `"assets"` operation in the `"pubspec.yaml"` file. I clicked pub get. But I am getting a problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z18p.png)

Comment: Some aseet is missing. Please check the first line

Comment: If you create assets folder top of resimler. You need to declare assets/resimler/ . Can you share with us your pubspec to understand what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to include images in your app**

**1. Create an assets/images folder**

- This should be located in the root of your project, in the same folder as your `pubspec.yaml` file.
- In Android Studio you can right click in the Project view
- You don't have to call it `assets` or `images`. You don't even need to make `images` a subfolder. Whatever name you use, though, is what you will register in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

**2. Add your image to the new folder**

- You can just copy your `image` into `assets/images`. The relative path of `lake.jpg`, for example, would be `assets/images/lake.jpg`.

**3. Register the assets folder in pubspec.yaml**

- Open the `pubspec.yaml` file that is in the root of your project.
- Add an `assets` subsection to the `flutter` section like this:

> 

```
flutter:
    assets:
      - assets/images/lake.jpg
```

- If you have multiple images that you want to include then you can leave off the file name and just use the directory name (include the final `/`):

> 

```
flutter:
    assets:
      - assets/images/
```

**4. Use the image in code**

- Get the asset in an Image widget with `Image.asset('assets/images/lake.jpg')`.

**5. Restart your app**